# Hibernate one to many repository can't find older entries

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `heroic_quality`
(
    `id`   INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(515) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `hero`
(
    `id`         INT            NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`       VARCHAR(515)   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `quality_id` INT            DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY  (`quality_id`) REFERENCES heroic_quality (id),
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

And the objects in hibernate are

```
@Table(name = "heroic_quality")
@Entity(name = "heroic_quality")
public class HeroicQuality
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Hero> heroes;

    //ommited getters and setters for shortness
}


@Table(name = "hero")
@Entity(name = "hero")
public class Hero
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    //ommited getters and setters for shortness
}
```

Notice that I do not want to have reference to HeroicQuality in my Hero object.

I also have a repository

```
@Repository
public interface HeroicQualityDAO
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HeroicQuality, Long>
{
    Optional<HeroicQuality> findByHeroesName(String heroName);
}
```

My database has the following data.

[image: Data inside my database]

The problem I am having is whenever I call `findByHeroesName` if the parameter is `Joan of Arc` then `isPresent()` returns true. However if the parameter is `Queen Boudica` or `Barbos` then `isPresent()` is false and I can't get quality object.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

The code I execute each time is

```
    Optional<HeroicQuality> foundquality = qualities.findByHeroesName(hero.getName());
    if (foundquality.isPresent())
    {
        log.info(foundquality.get().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        log.info("Quality not found");
    }
```

And I will only get data for `Joan of Arc`.
I am at a loss as to why this is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the JPA didn't generate the database schema from your entity model, the right query cannot produced.

If you look at the query produced:

```
select heroicqual0_.id as id1_2_, heroicqual0_.name as name2_2_ from heroic_quality heroicqual0_ left outer join hero heroes1_ on heroicqual0_.id=heroes1_.id where heroes1_.name=?
```

`heroicqual0_.id=heroes1_.id` this part causes the problem.  The only records having the same value on `id` columns on both tables are `(4, 'God Visions')` and `(4, ‘Joan of Arc’, 4)`

The join should have been like this: `heroic_quality.id = hero.quality_id`

You can write a query to get the desired output:

```
@Repository
public interface HeroicQualityDAO extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HeroicQuality, Long>
{
    @Query(value="select * from heroic_quality q join hero h on q.id=h.quality_id where h.name=:name", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<HeroicQuality> findByHeroesName(@Param("name") String heroName);
}
```